# Why cant I eager load my associated Customer details?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have created a method in my Laravel app to fetch my `Queue` model along with its related `User` model.

Heres what my Queue.php model looks like:

```
class Queue extends Model
{

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
...
```

Heres what my controller looks like:

```
    public function showQueue(Request $request)
    {
        $key = $request->session()->get('session_key');
        return $queue = Queue::where('session_id', $key)->with('customer')->get();
...
```

When I do this this is what my controller returns:

```
[
    {
    "id": 37,
    "user_id": 2,
    "queue_entry_time": "2020-08-09 02:17:07",
    "created_at": "2020-08-09T01:17:07.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-09T01:17:07.000000Z",
    "session_id": "ctwr4oqn7v4808oow8sooggosc04wk0",
    "customer": null
    }
]
```

The customer attribute is empty, but the customer is really just a User (model), you can see an ID exists under user_id, and there is a record that exists with that ID in the database.

Why is the `customer` attribute empty?

Comment: Are you certain the user #2 isn't soft-deleted?

Comment: I just checked, the user is there. I don't have soft deletes enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because It's incorrectly mapped by laravel itself. For your relation it will resolved to `customer_id` as official docs says:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.

So, you have to set a second parameter of your relation which specify the name of your foreign key of Queue entity.

```php
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
```

Comment: My User model uses `id` so the standard `belongsTo` should work without having to manually define the column.

Comment: But foreign_key in that case don't specify the column key on User entity, but on Queue entity instead, and your function name for Queue relation is *customer*, so it will search in Queue entity field with name `customer_id` (instead, you have field with name `user_id`)

Comment: I'm quite surprised, I have done what you have suggested and its working. What's got me confused is because in other areas of my app, I have a blade template where I do `Queue::find(X)->customer()->name` and this works fine without the changed mentioned above.